# How to vary a Materialize modal based on trigger button?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I'm using the Materialize CSS and have a working modal for creating new model instances. When I click the edit button on an instance, I want to open the same modal only with the fields pre-populated.

In bootstrap I could accomplish this using

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val('new value')
})
```

This function doesn't appear to work using Materialize. Is there an equivalent function I can use instead?

Answer (score 0):

So this method is not available on the Materialize framework but they do have a callback available for modal open.

In the initialization of the model, you're able to add optional parameters. Instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
});
```

you can add a modal open callback using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal({
        ready: function(modal, trigger) {
            alert("Modal Open");
        }
    });
});
```